# Error in ggplot2 could not find function "ggplot2" tidyverse in jupyter

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter, tidyverse

In Jupyter notebook, launched from Anaconda Navigator Individual Edition, with an R environment,

I ran

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

Then I ran

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
sample <- c(7,12,13,17,18,20,22,24,25,30,45)
ggplot2(sample)
```

I get warnings

```
> Warning message: "package 'tidyverse' was built under R version
> 3.6.3"-- Attaching packages --------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.3.0 -- v ggplot2 3.3.2     v purrr   0.3.4 v tibble  3.0.3
> v dplyr   1.0.1 v tidyr   1.1.1     v stringr 1.4.0 v readr   1.3.1   
> v forcats 0.4.0 Warning message: "package 'ggplot2' was built under R
> version 3.6.3"Warning message: "package 'tibble' was built under R
> version 3.6.3"Warning message: "package 'tidyr' was built under R
> version 3.6.3"Warning message: "package 'purrr' was built under R
> version 3.6.3"Warning message: "package 'dplyr' was built under R
> version 3.6.3"-- Conflicts ------------------------------------------
> tidyverse_conflicts() -- x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter() x
> dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
```

And then

> Error in ggplot2(sample): could not find function "ggplot2" Traceback:

Answer (score 0):

Traps for complete beginners
the actual command is ggplot